# Is there a way to solve the error of make rstan

Tags: r, compiler-errors, rstan

I use `CentOS6.8` ,R version is `3.4.0`,gcc version is `4.47`,when i use offline install by R CMD INSTALL rstan_2.14.1.tar.gz or higher version ,The error is:`make *** [chains.o]Error 1`,what is the chains.o and how can i solve it.Help!

```
/opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:In function`void boost::throw_exception(const E&)`:
/opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:70:error`enable_ both:` is not a member of `boost::exception_detail`
In file included from /opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/random/detail/integer_log2.hpp:19,
from /opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/random/detail/large_arithmetic.hpp:19,
from /opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/random/detail/const_mod.hpp:23,
from /opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp:30,
from /opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/random/additive_combine.hpp:27,
from chains.cpp:29:
/opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/pending/integer_log2.hpp:At global scope:
/opt/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include/boost/pending/integer_log2.hpp:7:note:#pragma message :This header is deprecated .Use <boost/integer/integer_log2.hpp> instead.
make: *** [chains.o] Error 1
Error:compilation failed for package `rstan`
```

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings or console messages before that singular uninspiring error message?

Comment: i have add more error message ,thankyou

Comment: Using `g++` 4.47 or anything less than 4.9 is not going to work with rstan 2.18.x or higher. And it seems that whatever version of rstan you were trying to compile does not work with BH 1.69.0.

Comment: I got the same error on Azure with a virtual machine Standard_F2s_v2, Ubuntu 19.04, R 3.4.3, and `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on Azure with a virtual machine `Standard_F2s_v2`, Ubuntu `19.04`, `R 3.4.3`, and `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609` because I was using

```r
devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
```

and my `DESCRIPTION` had:

```
Imports:
    rstan (>= 2.18.2),
```

The solution was to install packages separately without versions:

```r
.libPaths(c("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4", .libPaths()))
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN = "https://cran.r-project.org")))
packages <- c("devtools", ..., "rstan")
for (p in packages) {
  install.packages(p)
}
```

See [this Github branch](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/tree/62-fix-azure), commit 1b3d1f6, for the full details of the successful build.